# Can I write books and make Simoleons without being the writer job?

Tags: the-sims-3

In the Sims 3, can I quit my job as a writer with a Level 10 Writing Skill and still make money from writing books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll get Royalty fees depending on how good the book is once a week. If you want to write an Article, you'll have to be a writer.